# How to make an Android client and Spring boot RESTful server?

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot

An Android app which can able to act as a REST client and getting requested services from a Spring boot RESTful server by using API.

Answer (score 0):

To develop this RESTful Android client application with Spring boot server, we can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) REST client library for Android and we can read Spring boot [RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) documentation to develop this server.

For sake of better support, I also created this simple RESTful server. Check my [GitHub](https://github.com/Subarata-Talukder/Spring-REST-full-Server) repository to get this code.